# Using dataset.write_with_schema results in column name order that is different from the dataframe

Tags: dataiku

In dataiku, I have a new pandas dataframe that I am writing to a dataset using

dataset.write_with_schema(df) where df is my dataframe.

However, in the written dataset, I noticed that the column order is different from the pandas dataframe itself. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: which dataiku version you are working with ?